# Find all table names with column name?

Tags: sql-server

How can I get all the table names where the given column name exists? I want the names with "Like" in sql server. For example :-

```
  select TableNames where columnname like '%MyColumn%'
```

Please help me

Comment: **not duplicate** because this question calls for `LIKE` so is a broader request. The selected answer provides the column name as well to address the variability of column names that LIKE will return.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Please try the below query. Use sys.columns to get the details :-

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%MyCol%';
```

Comment: and to see schema name add SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)

Comment: Is there any way to select the name of the database in this query as well?

Comment: @KolobCanyon use this DB_NAME()

Comment: @KolobCanyon this search works only on the database you are on since the sys.column table is a system table (or view not sure) that is created on every DB. If you want to search through different DBs, that would be a more complex process, probably would imply using a loop that iterates through the differents DBs.

Comment: thank you so much for this. I've been coming back here frequently (for the past few months) for this query. Thought I'd leave a thank you comment haha!

Answer (score 30):

You could do this:

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%MyColumn%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Reference:

- [SQL SERVER – Query to Find Column From All Tables of Database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/06/sql-server-query-to-find-column-from-all-tables-of-database/)

Answer (score 20):

Try Like This:
For SQL SERVER 2008+

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%MyColumnaName%'
```

Or

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%MyName%'
```

Or 
Something Like This:

```
SELECT name  
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE OBJECT_ID IN ( SELECT id 
              FROM syscolumns 
              WHERE name like '%COlName%' )
```

Comment: is the 1st one generic & 2nd one specific to sql server or something like this?

Comment: @PSatishPatro both for sql server only